# Sencha Touch: Navigation View ui item won't change

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am trying to set the 'ui' property of my navigation view to light, but it only shows in the dark theme. Here's my view. What am I missing?

```
Ext.define('VisitTCMIndy.view.Social', {
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
xtype: 'socialcard',

config: {
    iconCls: 'chat',
    title: 'Social',
    layout: 'card',
    ui: 'light',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Social',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    flex: 1,
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'image',
                            baseCls: 'socialbutton',
                            title: 'Facebook',
                            src: "resources/images/facebookbutton.png",
                            flex: 1
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'image',
                            baseCls: 'socialbutton',
                            title: 'Twitter',
                            src: "resources/images/twitterbutton.png",
                            flex: 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    flex: 1,
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'image',
                            baseCls: 'socialbutton',
                            title: 'Pinterest',
                            src: "resources/images/pinterestbutton.png",
                            flex: 1
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'image',
                            baseCls: 'socialbutton',
                            title: 'Instagram',
                            src: "resources/images/instagrambutton.png",
                            flex: 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Take a Picture',
                    style: 'margin:3%'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you want to change the `ui` of the navigation bar of the navigation view, then should do this:

```
config: {
  iconCls: 'chat',
  title: 'Social',
  layout: 'card',
  navigationBar: {
    ui: 'dark'
  }
...
```

Hope this helps